# Retrieve the Financial Year data

Tags: sql, financial

How to access the data from MSSQL table

User will give only month(3) and financial year(2013-14), how can I retrieve the progress up to last month (previous month) and up to month (this month) while data has been inserted from jun-2013 to march-2014

I have tried but I have given like month 3 and financial year 2013-14 but its calculate only two month data while it should be calculate Apr-2013 to Mar-2014 data

My table structure is like

```
+--------+-------+------+---------+
| amount | month | year | finyear |
+--------+-------+------+---------+
| 12456  |   2   | 2013 | 2013-14 |
+--------+-------+------+---------+
```

thanks

Comment: If your user supplies month 3, and financial year (fiscal year) 2013-2014, you *actually* want results for the date range 2013-04-01 to . . . when? (*This* month is May, 2014. *Previous* month is April, 2014.)

Comment: I think the month here is calendar month and not related to the fiscal year at all. I don't understand the question either. It says data is from june 2013 to march 2014 but evaluation from april 2013 to march 2014. ??

Comment: You haven't defined what the financial year is, is it January to December? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
SELECT SUM(a.amount) + SUM(b.amount)
FROM table a
INNER JOIN table b ON b.year = a.year - 1
WHERE a.finyear = '2013 - 14'
AND a.month <= 3
AND b.month > 3
```

Although your data structure and example data is pretty confusing..